# How to access remote mysql server from dev environment on windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, windows-10, debian

**Actual config**
I have 2 VPS (Debian 9) :

- vps1 : php 7.3 & nginx
- vps2 : mariadb

Everything is fine.

**I'm trying to set up a dev config on my windows 10**

- windows 10 + php + nginx would replace vps1
- vps2 : no change, I do not want to install the database on my PC

**Problem**
I set up php and nginx but when I run //localhost I have an error related to mysql driver : *could not find driver*.

I checked phpInfo, all mysqli, mysqlnd, pdo, pdo_mysql drivers are loaded.

If anyone has an idea how to solve this problem I would be grateful.

Comment: If it's a remote sql server, why use localhost ? Shouldn't you use the servers ip address ? Also make sure the sql server is listening on external interface and the firewall is open on the mysql  port.

Comment: The SQL server is listening on external port, vps1 has access. I want to have a dev station on windows with all the pages from the site (php, css, ...) but have access to the sql server